# How do you pipe the output of sort to a combined xargs, -exec?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file with a list of ".m" entries, like this

> Foo.m
>   Bar.m

I want to replace every '.m' with '.h', sorted and keep the uniques like so.

```
cat ../classes.txt | sed 's/\.m/\.h/' | sort -u
```

This give me the same list only as '.h' entries, i.e.

> Foo.h
>   Bar.h

The second part is about printing to stdout every file that imports the headers above.

i.e. for a simple entry, it looks like so

```
echo Foo.h | xargs -I file find Classes -name \*.m -exec grep -q 'import "file' {} \; -print
```

However, when piping the output of the first to the second, I get nothing on the stdout.

i.e.

```
cat ../classes.txt | sed 's/\.m/\.h/' | sort -u | xargs -I file find Classes -name \*.m -exec grep -q 'import "file' {} \; -print
```

What gives?

Comment: Is the `"` in `"file` a typo?

Comment: Try using `xargs -t` (print command to stderr) to see if each command it's issuing is what you expect.

Comment: @1_CR not a typo. It's there to match #import "Foo.h"

Comment: Seems working here. Make sure your paths are correct? Also you can use `tee` between your pipes to 'see' what is passing trough them, e.g. `.. sort -u |tee /dev/stderr| xargs ..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @adurdin's response, found out that the command was

```
{} ; -print -name *.m -exec grep -q import "Foo.h
```

Which didn't make much sense.
Then realised that the classes.txt file had CRLF line terminators which caused it to choke.

**Changing the line ending to Unix format, worked like a charm.**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I follow enough to answer why you're seeing the behaviour you're seeing, but as an alternative I'd try something like this:

```
while read line; do
   find Classes -iname "*.m" -exec grep -q "import \"${line}" '{}' ;\
done < ../classes.txt | sort -u
```